# How do I show the values ​in the 'receitas', 'despesas' and 'saldo' boxes each time the addValues() method is executed?

Tags: typescript

I'm creating a finance website where, every time the user enters values, the boxes at the top are updated with these values, but it appears that the "value" property does not exist in prev. How could I make this work?

```
public addValues(): Obj[] | (undefined & void) {

        let inputValue = document.getElementById('valor') as HTMLInputElement;

        let inputNameValue = document.getElementById('nome-valor') as HTMLInputElement;

        let enterChecked = document.getElementById('entrada') as HTMLFormElement;
        let leftChecked = document.getElementById('saida') as HTMLFormElement;

            let list: Obj = {
                id: Math.random(),
                valor: this.normalizeNumbers(+inputValue.value),
                nomeValor: String(inputNameValue.value),
                checked: enterChecked.checked ? '<i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-arrow-up arrowUp-icon"></i>' : leftChecked.checked ? '<i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-arrow-down arrowDown-icon"></i>' : undefined
        }
        inputValue.value = ''
        inputNameValue.value = ''

        if (enterChecked.checked) {
            this.updatePositiveValues(this.valores)
        } else if (leftChecked.checked) {
            this.updateNegativeValues(this.valores)
        }

        if (enterChecked.checked) enterChecked.checked = false
        else if (leftChecked.checked) leftChecked.checked = false

        this.valores.push(list)
        this.createList()

        this.closeModal()

        return this.valores
    }
    private normalizeNumbers(value: number): string {
        const newValue = value.toLocaleString("pt-BR",{
            style: "currency",
            currency: "BRL"
        })
        return newValue
    }

    private updatePositiveValues(arr: Obj[]) {
        const positiveValue = arr.filter((item) => {
            item.checked == 'enterChecked'
        }).reduce((prev, curr) => {
            return prev.valor + curr.valor
        }, this.valores[0].valor)
        this.receitas.innerText = this.normalizeNumbers(+positiveValue)
        this.saldo.innerText = this.normalizeNumbers(+positiveValue)
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6h1jE.png)